# How to copy/paste test steps in test case viewed in browser?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

If I am editing a test case using Microsoft Test Manager (2017), I can select a set of test steps and then copy and paste them into the same or a different test case.

Is it possible to do the same thing when editing the test case from the browser (TFS 2017)? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option "[Edit Selected test cases in grid view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286729.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Create%20manual%20test%20cases)" in the test case context menu, you can copy/paste test steps with the feature in browser.

But unfortunately the feature is missed in TFS 2017 Update1, So you cannot copy/paste the test steps by editing the test case from the browser if you are using TFS 2017 Update1.

As a workaround you can create a test case query, then open the query in Excel, then copy/paste test steps cross test cases, then publish the update.

**Edit Selected test cases in grid view** option is back in the latest [TFS 2017 Update2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update2). So, you can also upgrade to the latest TFS 2017 Update2, then edit case within the grid view.
[image]

Comment: @Matthew Watson Have you resolved the issue by above workaround?

Comment: Upgrading to Update 2 will fix this, so I'll mark this as the answer. In the meantime I'll use the Microsoft Test Manager application to edit the test cases.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Is there any way to do this in bulk?  I would like to be able to export all test cases to excel and then have someone make updates in excel then re-import them in to vsts?